# Не берёт адрес из переменной, выдаёт ошибку "Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен"

Tags: python, сокет

Делаю задания из учебника по Python. Нужно было брать адрес из запроса пользователя и отправлять запрос на сервер. Если я адрес вручную вставляю в socket, всё нормально. Когда этот же адрес берётся из переменной, то выдаёт ошибку. Причём тип всё равно string выдаёт. Я не понимаю, в чём проблема!?

Адрес странички: [Учебный адрес](http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt). Домен, соответственно: data.pr4e.org

```js
import socket

inp = input('What link do we look?\n')

HOST = ''

def host_get(link):
    if link.find('//'):
        http = link.find('//') + 2
        new_link = link[http:].split('/')
        HOST = str(new_link[0])
        print(repr(HOST))
        print(HOST)
    else:
        new_link = link.split('/')
        HOST = str(new_link[0])
        print(HOST)

host_get(inp)
print(type(HOST))

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80)) # вручную вставлять всё ок, со ссылкой на переменную HOST не получается. Хотя и print и type подтверждают, что всё аналогично.
cmd = 'GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode() % inp.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
```

Comment: Вы меняете локальную переменную HOST внутри функции, а глобальную не меняете. В глобальном HOST остаётся пустая строка, оттого и ошибка

Comment: Спасибо большое! @andreymal